# Can't find the exe for anaconda installer

Tags: anaconda

[image]

I use a 64-bit Windows 10 machine. I was trying to install Anaconda by following the steps mentioned on [this DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows#install) page. I was expecting a .exe file, instead, I got a .pkg file. I don't know how to open the .pkg file. I could see .exe files in [Anaconda's archive](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/). Not sure which one to download. Any help?

Comment: `.pkg` files are generally `macOS` format, so maybe you tried the incorrect one.

Comment: Have you tried this:  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

Comment: @Ansi, I opened the link you shared. The first step mentioned in that page is to download the installer.I am facing the issue in the first step.

Comment: @I'L'I, I think I got the issue. When I land on the anaconda download page, by default it shows me the links to .pkg files. when I click on the Windows icon on the top it shows .exe files.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. You have to choose windows option cos it does not automatically detect you system. The default selected is for mac OS and thus it will download the pkg version. Its after downloading that I found out and had to redownload it.
Its really a poor web design, since the options don't really appear as options (they appear as saying anaconda is available in all these platforms) and are visibly in another section.

Answer (score 0):

By default the anaconda website will set the option to MAC OS(.pkg is MAC extension) change and download by windows it works!

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda often downloads the pkg version for Macs.  If using windows you might want the .exe version.  Make sure you click Windows on the main page to download that installer.  You can also go here: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

Find the .exe version for windows - download it and install it.